# Rest Assured - comparing the json path with another

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have json for example below

```
{"TestJson":{  
  "Result":"Passed",
  "description":"Passed."},
  "Students":[{  
     "Class":{  
        "Primary":"Yes"
     },
     "Course":{  
        "Enrolled":"yes",
         "AccountNumber":"2387287382"
     },
     "AccountNumber":"2387287382",
     "Paid":"Yes"
  }]}
```

I am wondering how can I find a good solution for this.

What I currently do

```
.body("Students[0].Course.AccountNumber",equalTo("2387287382"))
.body("Students[0].AccountNumber",equalTo("2387287382"))
```

---

My test criteria is to check key `Students[0].AccountNumber` matches `Students[0].Course.AccountNumber`

---

I want to do in this way, but i am not able to find a solution something like

```
.body("Students[0].Course.AccountNumber",equalTo("Students[0].AccountNumber"))
```

The above wont work obviously, but that is how I want to compare. basically comparing the key with another key and they should match.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
String A = 
given ().
when().
get/put/post({api/name})
.extract()
.path("Students[0].Course.AccountNumber");

String B = 
given ().
when().
get/put/post({api/name})
.extract()
.path("Students[0].AccountNumber");

Assert.assertEquals(A, B);
```

Seems like this workaround is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Use the response to verify other parts of the response](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#use-the-response-to-verify-other-parts-of-the-response) section of the rest-assured docs. You basically want to create a lambda implementing `ResponseAwareMatcher<Response>`. Something like this:

```
get("/x").then().body("href", response -> equalTo("http://localhost:8080/" + response.path("userId"));
```